# Running more than one instance of web APP on local host on the same machine

Tags: angular, spring-boot, web, localhost

I'm implementing an angular application for front-end & java spring boot for back-end.
my application simulates Gmail and I want to run two instances of the application on my computer on the local host to send messages to each other and notice what will happen for back-end and DB.
Specifically, I want to run my application (front-end specially) twice to send email from one of them to another to show the displaying of emails.
How can I do that ??

I thought to run my front-end on different local ports but I faced problem about how to make my back-end send responses to each port separatly.

Comment: try different hostnames and run behind a reverse proxy like nginx

Answer (score 0):

You can simply open your application on the same address and port, e.g. `http://localhost:4200`, in an incognito tab.

Tabs in normal browser usage and incognito are handled independently.